# What is PML4 short for?

Tags: linux, paging, xen

In Xen code ./xen/include/asm-x86/config.h, I saw the memory layout code is:

```
/*
137  * Meng: Xen-definitive guide: P81
138  * Memory layout:
139  *  0x0000000000000000 - 0x00007fffffffffff [128TB, 2^47 bytes, PML4:0-255]
140  *    Guest-defined use (see below for compatibility mode guests).
141  *  0x0000800000000000 - 0xffff7fffffffffff [16EB]
142  *    Inaccessible: current arch only supports 48-bit sign-extended VAs.
143  *  0xffff800000000000 - 0xffff803fffffffff [256GB, 2^38 bytes, PML4:256]
```

I'm very confused at what the PML4 is short for. I did know that the x86_64 only uses 48 bits out of 64bits. But what is the PML4 short for? It may help me understand the number behind it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's short for **Page Map Level 4**. A bit of explanation can be found [here](http://www.pagetable.com/?p=14). Basically it's just the way AMD decided to label page tables.

Comment: Thank you very much! The reference is very useful! It's like the page table entry at the 4 levels page table. So I guess the offset of the PML table is A12-A20?